# How to determine whether two arbitrary random variables are independent?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I have known how to tell whether two continuous random variables or two discrete random variables are independent. But is there a genetic method to tell **two arbitrary random variables** are independent? For example, **a continuous and a discrete**? 
Thank a lot for your kind answer.

Comment: Joint CDF is a product of marginal CDF's.

Comment: In some cases characteristic functions provide an easy way of proving independence.

Comment: Sometimes a Necessary condition  can be useful...Necessary Condition for stochastic independence of 2 rv's is that their joint domain is rectangular so, for example, if their domain is a triangle, you immediately know that the 2 variables are NOT independent

Comment: If CDF is unknown, there are only sample values. Can use hypothesis testing to test the independence? For example, we can use contingency table and chi-square testing to test whether two discrete random variables are independent or not. This's a tutorial https://courses.lumenlearning.com/introstats1/chapter/test-of-independence/

Answer (score 0):

Independence by definition means that for arbitrary RVs $A$, $B$; $P(A)P(B) = P(A \cap B)$. That is the generic method.

Comment: Your definition of independence makes sense if $A, B$ are _events_ (rather than random variables).